# retaining checked items after a databind()

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

I am populating a data table which in turn populates a checkboxlist. I want the items to be selected when they are added. I can do this, however when I add a 2nd -> nth Item, it only keeps the last check box. Is there a way to persist selected check boxes through a bind? here is my current function:

```
protected void FinalizeAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    VersionDataTable.AddVersionDataTableRow(Convert.ToInt32(VersionDropDown.SelectedValue), ProductDropDown.SelectedItem.Text + " " + VersionDropDown.SelectedItem.Text);

    ProductCheckList.DataSource = VersionDataTable;

    ProductCheckList.DataValueField = VersionDataTable.VersionIDColumn.ToString();
    ProductCheckList.DataTextField = VersionDataTable.VersionTextColumn.ToString();
    ProductCheckList.DataBind();

    ProductCheckList.Items[ProductCheckList.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the selected items before you databind the CheckboxList again.

For example(sorry for VB.NET, but i think you'll understand what i mean):

```
Dim oldSelection = (From item As ListItem In ProductCheckList.Items
                    Where item.Selected).ToList
' databinding '
If oldSelection.Any Then
    For Each selectedItem In oldSelection
        Dim item = ProductCheckList.Items.FindByValue(selectedItem.Value)
        If Not item Is Nothing Then
           item.Selected = True
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot on monday and report back.

Comment: Ok, but when you are also using LINQ to get the old selected items, remember that you have to execute it immediately(e.g. with `ToList()` like above), because otherwise it would be executed after the databinding([deferred execution](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c16935)) and the selection would be cleared again.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong when assigning to oldSelection, intellisense is not picking up "item". I have not used LINQ before, so it might be an issue with my knowledge base.

Comment: @Contristo: What target-framework version are you using(look into advanced compiler settings in your project)? It should be at least 3.5. Is `System.Core.dll` added as reference? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx

Comment: Ok, I solved it using a variant inspired by your answer, basically mapped the checkboxlist to a List<bool> and ran a for loop to reselct items after the databind. Thanks again for the help man!